# SOQL: Convert set to list

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql

I am trying to get unique items from an object so I am starting with a set however I need the values to be returned as a list for the visualforce `<apex:selectOptions>` component. I have tried the code below, and variations, but I keep getting errors related to the type not being set correctly. Can anyone help me out? Is there a better way of populating a list with unique values from a SOQL query?

```
    public List<SelectOption> getItems() {

        Set<License__c> license = new Set<License__c>( [SELECT Name FROM License__c] );
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
            options.addAll(license);
        return options;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No need to work with lists and sets if you group-by in the query:

```
    public List<SelectOption> getItems() {
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
        for(AggregateResult l : [SELECT Name FROM License__c GROUP BY Name]){ 
            options.add(new SelectOption(String.valueOf(l.get('Name')),String.valueOf(l.get('Name'))));
        }
        return options;
    }
```

Comment: I like you method the best so far but it is generating an error.

Comment: Loop variable must be an SObject or list of AggregateResult

Comment: Ah you're right it has to loop through aggregateresult because of the grouping. I corrected that now. Slightly less clean because we then have to fetch the values and convert to string, although still the most efficient way of doing it I believe

Answer (score 11):

Simplest way:

`new List<String>( new Set<String> {'a', 'b', 'c'} );`

Comment: Perfect.  Also `Set<String> foo = new Set<String>(); new List<String>(foo);`

Comment: @ShaneK that's exactly same

Comment: It is essentially the same.  But the point is you can initialize a Set and alter it as much as you like, and then cast it to a List later.  Its just for clarity because at first glance your example might suggest you have to use a static initializer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a list of [`SelectOptions`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_pages_selectoption.htm). The set you have is not the same type, so you have to iterate over them, and create `SelectOption` objects, then add them to the list.

```
for (License__c l: license) {
    options.add(new SelectOption(l.Name, l.Id));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want unique elements, you could tweak your SOQL to get distinct names. Since the DISTINCT keyword is not supported by SOQL, one workaround is to use GROUP

`SELECT Name, COUNT(Name) FROM License__c GROUP BY Name`

Answer (score 0):

If someone like me enjoys using the array notation for the lists like:

```
Id[] ids = new Id[]{};
```

instead of,

```
List<Id> ids = new List<Id>();
```

to create a list from a set would be as the following,

```
Set<Id> idSet = new Set<Id>();
Id[] idList = new List<Id>(idSet);
```

So Set and Map don't have any other notations as far as I know. So assuming we have a Set of IDs called idSet. If you want to use the array notation to create a list and populate it with all the IDs from idSet, you would still need to use the List notation on the right-hand side of the expression. So you CAN NOT do,

```
Id[] idList = new Id[](idSet);
```

I hope this helps you sugar-coat your code the way you like it. Cheers!